# Use Webpack's DefinePlugin vars in Jest tests

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I'm pretty new in React, coming from Angular. I'm writing some tests for the code that's going to send request to an external endpoint. Obviously, I don't want to hardcode a real host in production code so I thought I could use webpack's `DefinePlugin` to keep this in a constant.

How to configure Webpack and Jest together to use Webpack's capabilities?

Comment: I think it is not possible theoretically, because webpack define plugin's variables are available `after` webpack's compile, however jest scripts runs  `before` compiling.

Comment: @arikanmstf Writing tests with Karma and angular I was able to run them from webpack level so that's why I'm curious :)

Comment: @arikanmstf it's definitely doable. you can easily define a common globals.js file which exports a key/val object and require it in both jest and webpack for synchronisation...

Answer (score 42):

It's just like that in your package.json or jest.config.js :

`"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    }
  }`

If you still have any problems, please check the jest offical docs here:

[globals-object](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object)

Comment: This works perfectly. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Is this the only way? Is there a way to connect jest straight to the webpack defined plugins?

Comment: I'm not sure why but I had to put it in the "jest.config.js" file, when it was in "package.json" it was ignored.

Comment: Got this issue in 2023, and still working. :)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments:

1. `/globals.js`

```
module.exports = {
  __DEV__: true
}
```

2. `/webpack.config.js`

```
const globals = require('./globals.js')

// ...

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(globals)
]
```

3. `/jest.config.js`

```
const globals = require('./globals.js')

module.exports = {
  // ...
  globals,
}
```

Comment: this does not work in case of string because Webpack replace the source code with the value, instead jest assign the value to the variable. So, supposing `x` to be `"myConfigPath"`, in jest it must be `{x: "myConfigPath"}` instead in jest it must be `{x: '"myConfigPath"'}` since webpack replace the variable instead of assign a value to it

Comment: indeed, i forgot to mention it ; thanks for the precision it will surely help others :)